# How to show details from table to modal popup using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angular

Please have a look at 3rdpage if i click the eye icon the transaction details modal popup and show the value from table behind it. i want if i first row then it shows only first row details like that. if I click 2nd row it shows sec row... HOW to??

[this is my component.TS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHdyW.png)

[this is my html modal template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13rw4.png)

[this is my demo project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x5h0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is no need to iterate transactionsData inside modal.Modal should receive only row data object .You have to pass single row data on the eventHandler of eye button click.
[You can refer this sample](https://therichpost.com/angular-12-open-bootstrap-5-modal-popup-with-dynamic-data-on-button-click-table-row/)

Comment: yes bro i referred the sample but my point how to get the details from .ts file because i only store my datas there i want it from there...Any way to get that... Thanks for your answer bruhhhhhhhhhhhhh.....

Comment: Bro, What if the table datas are in the object i mean datas in the array obect????